# java regex for starting and trailing hyphens

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

input : `"c--","--c"`

o/p: `"c"`

Basically I want to remove starting and trailing hyphens. I am trying below two regex but no luck:

```
("([A-Za-z]+)([\\-]+)$"),"$1")

("[\\-]+)([A-Za-z]+)$"),"$2")
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(([A-Za-z]+)(?=-))|(?<=-)([A-Za-z]+)
```

This should match any letter with a starting or trailing hyphen

Answer (score 1):

The regex should be

```
str.replaceAll("^[-]+|[-]+$","")
```

Answer (score 1):

use this regex `((-+$)|(^\-+))` and replace matching group with ""

This will match one or more `-` at the beginning or end of a string and you can replace it with a null string